# Is there a way to close a modal window a few seconds after the form as been successfully submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm pretty new to js, I downloaded this plugin that creates a pop-up window when a user lands on the page. The plugin is called wp-super-popup. So i was wondering if there was a way to close the modal box after the user successfully submits the form. Right now it just says thank you but no action follows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, there's a way. On form submit set a timer to execute a function later. In that function close the popup. Keyword: [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: I'm kindof a newbie, would it be possible to show me an example @SergioTulentsev ?

Comment: Sure. [Just show some effort.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html)

Comment: Sergio has lead you down the correct path already. You need to identify a unique feature of the modal window that you need to close, such as the ID, Class, or perhaps even the name, rel, href, etc. Some dynamic attribute. Then, as he explained, execute a function WITHIN your submit function that applies a setTimeout with a $("target").remove(); (jQuery.Remove(); will remove the element from the DOM, if you don't want that, you can use several other methods.)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i've tried but I have no idead where to insert the code. I'm a novice!

Answer (score 0):

Capture the form submit.

```
$('#idOfMyForm').submit(function(){
```

Create a Timeout Function to remove the Modal Window.

```
//2000 represents 2 seconds
setTimeout("$('#myModalWindow').remove()", 2000 );
```

All together now.

```
$('#idOfMyForm').submit(function(){
  //2000 represents 2 seconds
  setTimeout("$('#myModalWindow').remove()", 2000 ); 
});
```

Should get you going in the right direction.